# How do I write a quotation mark inside quotation mark?

Tags: quotation-marks

I know that the convention is to use a single quotation inside double quotation marks. But what do I do when I ***must*** quote double quotation marks?

For instance, suppose I type `"adv:Monday"` in a search engine block. And I must convey to my readers that `"adv:Monday"` is exactly what I had typed in the search engine.

If I write `I searched "'adv:Monday'"`, I would be making a factually incorrect statement, albeit it'd be a grammatically correct one.

Comment: _I searched "adv:Monday" (including double quotes)_

Comment: Wouldn't that interpret to read that I searched adv:Monday as opposed to "adv:Monday"

Comment: Only if the reader ignored the "including double quotes" part of the instruction.

Comment: One can get precious about these things.  Where certain variants are forced, as here, one can use guillemets and add an explanation that everything within them must appear identically in the copied passage. // 'I know that the convention is to use a single quotation inside double quotation marks.' That's _one_ convention. And what about when one is giving a quote which uses one convention, but you're already using another?

Comment: Using blockquotes or similar is also a solution: you put the text including quotation marks on a separate line, and nothing that is not a direct quote. It's still better to explicitly say what you're doing, as in computer books that will say "type everything that follows and press <ENTER> at the end of the line".

Comment: The question as it stands seems too narrow to answer. The OP evidently knows how to put quotation marks inside quotation marks, but fears that other people will not understand this convention. There is no way to fix that conundrum just by putting quotation marks inside other quotation marks, and the OP needs to be open to an alternative solution.

Comment: How can it be grammatically correct or incorrect? This is merely writing, not speech. Same words, same order, same grammar. Punctuation is neither syntax nor morphology and therefore is not grammar.

Comment: Why not put another set of double quotes around the search term? If I saw that, I'd interpret it exactly as you mean it. ""adv: Monday""

Comment: " "adv: Monday" " is easier to scan.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a matter of grammar but of style:

> I searched `“adv:Monday”`.
>
> I searched *“adv:Monday”*.

Comment: Also: I searched "adv:Monday" (quotes included).